# Export contents of dom into html file chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dom, web, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to export the DOM (what you might see in the inspector) to an html file in Google Chrome Canary (beta version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can right-click the `html` tag and click `Edit as HTML`, and copy the text.

Comment: This doesn't seem to copy the contents of a nested <html> tag loaded by JavaScript.